# App with youtubeAPI display is blank with nothing in the Logcat and no error

Tags: android, json, youtube-data-api

I am running an app to embed channel in android app using youtube data API.

- Youtube API is imported
- Internet Permission is granted
- Youtube API key is generated

but when I run the app, it displays nothing. There is nothing displayed in Logcat. However, the Run tab displays these messages in blue.

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553)
W/System.err:     at com.currentmedia.channel.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:65)
W/System.err:     at com.currentmedia.channel.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:50)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

the MainActivity code is below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String API_Key = "API_KEY";
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<VideoDetails> videoDetailsArrayList;
    MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter;
    String url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCS5PDM-3ThA1BNhuyqWwG_w&maxResults=50&key={API_KEY}";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        videoDetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        myCustomAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, videoDetailsArrayList);


        displayVideos();
    }

        private void displayVideos () {
            RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject jsonVideoId=jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                            JSONObject jsonObjectsnippet=jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet");
                            JSONObject jsonObjectDefault=jsonObjectsnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium");

                            String video_id=jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");

                            VideoDetails vd=new VideoDetails();
                            vd.setVideoId(video_id);
                            vd.setTitle(jsonObjectsnippet.getString("title"));
                            vd.setDescription(jsonObjectsnippet.getString("description"));
                            vd.setUrl(jsonObjectDefault.getString("url"));

                            videoDetailsArrayList.add(vd);

                        }
                        listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
                        myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(), LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
            );
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

I cannot figure out what is meant by videoId has no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that, according to the official docs of the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint, the `id.videoId` may well not be present in each and every item of the result set obtained as response from that endpoint:

> [**id.videoId**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#id.videoId) (string)
> If the `id.kind` property's value is `youtube#video`, then this property will be present and its value will contain the ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify a video that matches the search query.

(Note that I did corrected the doc, replacing `id.type` with `id.kind`.)

That's very much acceptable, since, invoking `Search.list` on the URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCS5PDM-3ThA1BNhuyqWwG_w&maxResults=50&key={API_KEY}`

the result set provided back may well contain items that are not necessarily referring to videos; if fact the first entry has `id.kind` of value `youtube#channel`:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "2VoDDmPbFOrlKO9COuJvLIPTGsc",
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "regionCode": "...",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 70,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "qP4nftiUBo-HCqeTOulVW0GSmuI",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCS5PDM-3ThA1BNhuyqWwG_w"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2016-06-30T07:46:01Z",
        "channelId": "UCS5PDM-3ThA1BNhuyqWwG_w",
        "title": "Slimy guy",
        "description": "Hi Guys hope your all having a wonderful day I am a family friendly Youtuber, Gamer and a reactor I will also try to make some Vlogs.",
        "thumbnails": {
          ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "Slimy guy",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",
        "publishTime": "2016-06-30T07:46:01Z"
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

---

In case you're interested to obtain *only videos* from `Search.list`, then add the parameter [`type`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) to the invoking URL as `type=video`. Then your code will work OK, since, the API will return to you only items representing videos.

Nonetheless, is good practice to have an assert of the following form in your code:

```
assert jsonVideoId.getString("kind") == "youtube#video";
```

just before calling `jsonVideoId.getString("videoId")`.

(I do notice that the variable name `jsonVideoId` is unfortunate, since, the JSON [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#id) object, as already noted above, does not necessarily refer to videos only.)

Comment: I tried adding the code as mentioned but still not displaying anything

Comment: I tried changing channelID and found that there is id.kind is youtube#video. no youtube#channel id. kind... but same results. no value assigned to videoid

Comment: Did you added the `assert` statement I mentioned? If yes, did your app fired an `AssertionError` exception?

Comment: The structure `videoDetailsArrayList` should have been populated with many videos; check that out, e.g. by printing it out on the console, or by logging it.

Comment: ` JSONObject jsonVideoId=jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                            JSONObject jsonObjectsnippet=jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet");
                            JSONObject jsonObjectDefault=jsonObjectsnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium");
                            assert jsonVideoId.getString("kind") == "youtube#video";
                            String video_id=jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");

                            VideoDetails vd=new VideoDetails();
                            vd.setVideoId(video_id);`

Comment: I added the `assert` statement as mentioned. no AssertionError exception